# Login Authentication using JDBC and JSP : How to check if the username and Password entered by the user exists in the Database?

Tags: java, html, jsp, authentication, jdbc

Under JSP, after JDBC connection is successful, and ResultSet is showing some value.

***How can I check that the login values (username and password) entered by the user in the text field (using HTML form) is correct and present in the Database?***

EDIT: It shows incorrect username and password irrespective of the fact that the credentials are entered or not:

```
if (rs.next()) {
  out.printf("Welcome, %s! You've successfully logged in!\n", username);
} else {
  out.print("Incorrect username or password!");
}
if (username == "" || password == "") {
  out.print("<body>Username or password cannot be empty!</body>");
}
```

Comment: Post your code as well.

Comment: Put this `if(username=="" || password==""){..}` before your database code.

Comment: As @swati pointed out put that code above querying from database. And put all our code to query the code inside an else statement.

Comment: Alright! I've made the required changes, thanks! It's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you have already got the password and username from the form and the username and password are stored in the database as plane text. If that is the case then this sample code will help you :

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("url","username","password");
String sql = "select * from MyTable where username=? and password=?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, "yourUsername");
ps.setString(2, "yourPassword");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("login successful");
    //code to redirect to login page
}
```

Since there will only be a user with a given username, then if you query for a record having a specific username and password it will have a result if such a user exists. This can be accounted to a successful login.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works. But, what if I also want to give an "Incorrect username or password" error. I tried using else with the if, but that is giving me an error.

Comment: I am glad I could help.

Comment: @arunken you can't store user's password in DB as simple text. It should be hashed. Otherwise, you broke the security of your application. See the following link [Why should I hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36833/why-should-i-hash-passwords)

Comment: Obviously! But that isn't the case with the op who is trying to figure out how to successfully login. We can't expect them to use encryption or hashing in their first try. @nazar_art

Comment: @Aishwarya Else could work fine with the code. Can you please post the code so that we can understand the possible reason behind the error.